# SSRS result different from SSMS result with the same query and parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm doing a SSRS report but I have this problem that the SSRS data results is different when the script is run in SQL. I created a new datasource and link it to the dataset but still, the results were different. I tested it a lot of times and make sure I had the same parameter selected in my report and the same value entered in my SQL query but I still not had the same result. Can anyone help me with this? I really can't see the problem.

Comment: Can you please share more details: which query do you use, which parameter(s), what result you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Maybe a first step, is to simplify your report/query. Try to get rid of too much detail and try to concentrate on what you think the problem is (for instance the WHERE clause). This will also make it more suitable for posting here.

Comment: check to make sure your data source is pointing to the same server as your SSMS. Almost always this has been the source of such issues.

Comment: run a trace on the SQL server when you execute from SSRS, then see exactly what is being run. I can almost guarantee it will not be what you expected.

Comment: I'm pointing my data source to the same server in SSMS. Out of 30640 rows result in SSMS, 19 of them had different results when run in SSRS.